# How to convert from a matrix of strings to a matrix of symbolic expressions in Julia

Tags: julia

I would like to convert from a matrix of strings to a matrix of symbolic expressions.

```
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 "1/a"       "1/b"            "12"
 "a"         "1/a + b*b + c"  "0"    
 "1"         "0"              "0"
```

in Matlab, I would use

```
M=str2sym(T);
syms(symvar(M))
S = simplify(M);
```

but I can't find how to do it in Julia and Symbolics.jl

Please help
J.

Comment: Do you know the variables `a, b, c` beforehand, or are they also to be parsed?

Comment: If like @phipsgabler suggested, `a, b, c` are known, then `@variables a b c ; [eval(Meta.parse(x)) for x in A]` works (WARNING: parsing and evaluating strings is a security and general bug risk!)

Comment: The variable names are not known in advance, unfortunately. The matrix size is also unknown, only that it's always a square matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Unless there is some custom expression parsing specifically made for Symbolics, which I don't know about, you can use the builtins from Julia to just replicate what would happen if you were to enter those definitions "by hand" (the usual warnings about `eval`ing arbitrary code from untrusted sources applies).

If you already have the symbolic variables lying around, you can use `eval` and `parse` directly:

```
julia> eval.(Meta.parse.(T))
2×2 Matrix{Real}:
 1 / a                1
    12  c + 1 / a + b^2
```

If you don't have to figure out the variables yourself, you can wrap the definition:

```
julia> function build_expr(vars, T)
           s = size(T, 2)
           exprs = Meta.parse.(T)
           return quote
               @variables $(vars...)
               Base.hvcat($s, $(exprs...))
           end
       end
build_expr (generic function with 1 method)

julia> build_expr((:a, :b, :c), T)
quote
    #= REPL[5]:5 =#
    #= REPL[5]:5 =# @variables a b c
    #= REPL[5]:6 =#
    Base.hvcat((2, 2), 1 / a, 1, 12, 1 / a + b * b + c)
end
```

If you *do* have to figure out the variables, too, it gets complicated.  For some simplifying assumptions, this code could suffice:

```
function build_expr(T)
    s = size(T, 2)
    exprs = Meta.parse.(T)
    vars = mapreduce(get_free_vars, ∪, exprs)
    defs = Base.Generator(vars) do v
        :(@isdefined($v) ? nothing : @variables($v))
    end
    
    return quote
        $(defs...)
        Base.hvcat($s, $(exprs...))
    end
end

function get_free_vars(expr)
    vs = Set{Symbol}()
    MacroTools.postwalk(expr) do x
        if x isa Symbol
            push!(vs, s)
        end
    end

    return vs
end
```

It relies on figuring out all free variables (which includes known operators and functions), and testing them with `@isdefined` in the environment where you evaluate:

```
julia> build_expr(T)
quote
    #= REPL[44]:10 =#
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(a)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables a
    end
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(+)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables +
    end
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(/)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables /
    end
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(^)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables ^
    end
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(b)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables b
    end
    if #= REPL[44]:6 =# @isdefined(c)
        nothing
    else
        #= REPL[44]:6 =# @variables c
    end
    #= REPL[44]:11 =#
    Base.hvcat(2, 1 / a, 12, 1, c + 1 / a + b ^ 2)
end
```

Comment: I have found this as well `julia> eval.(Meta.parse.(T))
2×2 Matrix{Real}:
 1 / a                1
    12  c + 1 / a + b^2` but this output is wrong, the original string matrix is 3x3!

Comment: Yeah, because I was too lazy to retype your original T.

Comment: I still haven't solved it, but mostly due to lack of time. For those interested I started a repository for this project: https://github.com/ladmanj/jusyca